# Updating matrix and variance after loop

Tags: r, loops, vector, matrix, variance

I have an array with an 8X11 matrix called results2 and I'm trying to do two things iteratively (~1000 times).

1. randomly select 4 cells at a time in the matrix and either add or subtract a value to that selection. The values need to be added either this way (+, -, -, +) or this way (-,+,+,-). After doing this addition/subtraction, the 8X11 matrix should have the updated modification done on it and the process should repeat.
2. calculate and update the variance for each cell in the 8X11 matrix after every loop and save it into a vector. In the end there should 88 vectors with a variance value inside it--1 for each cell in the matrix.

What I have so far is:

```
r2 <- results[2,,]
dat <- r2[sample(prod(dim(r2)),4)] #randomly samples from the 8X11 matrix
dat <- as.matrix(dat) 

sampleRand <- function(dat) {
x_min = seq(0,min(sample(dat,4)), by=0.01) #random sampling for 4 cells and finds range       from 0 to the min of that sample
x.min = sample(x_min,1) # randomly selects the min to use to add or subtract by
flip = sample(0:1,1,rep=T) #if flip is = 1 then do +,-,-,+ if flip = 0 then do -,+,+,-
if(flip > 0) {
  dat[1,1] = dat[1,1] + x.min
  dat[2,1] = dat[2,1] - x.min
  dat[3,1] = dat[3,1] - x.min
  dat[4,1] = dat[4,1] + x.min
  if (dat[1,1] < 0 ||
      dat[2,1] < 0 ||
      dat[3,1] < 0 ||
      dat[4,1] < 0) 
{ print("FALSE")
}
} else if(flip == 0) { 
  dat[1,1] = dat[1,1] - x.min
  dat[2,1] = dat[2,1] + x.min
  dat[3,1] = dat[3,1] + x.min
  dat[4,1] = dat[4,1] - x.min
} else if (dat[1,1] < 0 ||
          dat[2,1] < 0 ||
          dat[3,1] < 0 ||
          dat[4,1] < 0)
{ print("FALSE")
}
}
```

The problem with the above code (aside from ugliness) is that I am selecting out values from the 8X11 matrix and modifying them. I am not modifying them directly in the 8X11 matrix. How can I do this?

Also, how can I calculate the variance for each cell in the 8X11 matrix and have the variance value update for that cell after each iteration?. Ideally, this variance value would be saved as it's own vector. So in the end there should be 88 vectors with a variance value in each.

thanks.

By the way, results is just a 3D array with 13,000 matrices that are 8X11 each. An example of matrix #2 in results is:

```
results[2,,]
      [,1]       [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]
[1,] 0.1108446 0.09536505 0.6639205 0.5750731 0.3526045 0.5534660 0.8835108
[2,] 0.2762736 0.16588542 0.5556568 0.6600122 0.4832881 0.4584993 1.0334293
[3,] 0.1313672 0.00000000 0.5799588 0.5835488 0.7482058 0.5714304 0.8910430
[4,] 0.1815236 0.50803010 0.4826228 0.7011605 0.5161530 0.3057819 0.9230045
[5,] 0.1363721 0.77955695 0.5983714 0.5894578 0.5964733 0.8284053 0.7949902
[6,] 0.2058215 0.54171493 0.3260954 0.6145317 0.5241678 1.1855122 0.9472204
[7,] 0.1398614 0.62403905 0.5403183 0.5141039 0.6353840 0.8727070 0.5891284
[8,] 0.1546674 0.54992965 0.8204701 0.6335292 0.5297555 0.9809781 0.6295093
      [,8]      [,9]     [,10]     [,11]
[1,] 0.9334862 0.7306472 0.6472618 1.0034951
[2,] 0.6672198 0.4258317 0.6736558 0.9045543
[3,] 0.7593824 0.5955351 0.5679406 1.0567393
[4,] 0.6764162 0.8904367 0.6936535 0.9122004
[5,] 0.8040301 0.6321197 0.3979384 0.9446451
[6,] 0.6828278 0.7215308 0.8486158 0.8146954
[7,] 0.7100341 0.6410416 1.2111213 0.9692271
[8,] 0.6010656 0.7648455 0.8935872 0.6057215
```

Comment: Can you provide a small, practice data set for us? What is `results`? Also, simplifying the code as much as possible would help get a quicker answer.

Comment: Kevin, I added an example. This is as simplified as I could get it.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd recommend writing the question so that others can generate the matrix in their own console without copy and paste.

```
r2 = matrix( runif(88), 8, 11 )
```

generates a 8 by 11 matrix of random numbers between 0 and 1. Next, you should probably use more built-in functions and vectorize your code. It will make it much easier to understand your intent. Does the code below do the same thing that you are doing now? I think it might. Work through it and see if it does. If it doesn't, then try to simplify your code in a similar way so it's easier to understand.

```
r2 = matrix( runif(88), 8, 11 )
dat = sample(r2,4)

sampleRand = function(dat) {
  x.min = sample( seq(0, min(dat), by=0.01), 1 )
  flip = sample(c(-1,1),1)
  dat = dat + flip*c(1,-1,-1,1)*x.min
  if( any(dat<0) ) print("FALSE")
}
```

You might also want to do some research on "assignment operators" and "replacement functions" in R. For updating four random elements of the `r2` matrix, see the code below.

```
cells = sample(length(r2),4)
r2[ cells ] = r2[ cells ] + c(1,-1,-1,1)
```